# How to set Caps Lock as Hyper (and change modifiers) using xkb?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard, xkb, xmodmap, setxkbmap

This is currently my `.xsessionrc` file:

```
xmodmap -e "remove Mod4 = Hyper_L" -e "add Mod3 = Hyper_L" -e "lock = Hyper_L" -e "keysym Caps_Lock = Hyper_L" &
bspwm &
xfdesktop -D &
```

What I did was unset `Hyper_L` as a `Mod4` modifier (which is taken by the `Super` key), remove it from the `Lock` modifier (because it also made uppercase letters), set it to `Mod3` and then bind the `Caps_Lock` key as `Hyper_L`.

This works, but I'd like to achieve this using `setxkbmap`. I know that I can just use `setxkbmap -option caps:hyper` but I should also set the appropriate modifiers and I have no idea on how to do this.

Also, is `.xsessionrc` the appropriate file to put such commands?

Comment: I'm really hoping you've figured out how to do this, I'm in need of this as well! I'm currently using `~/.Xmodmap`, but that doesn't always work consistently.